# How to upload GIF as image, rather than a video, on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When I select normal (**not animated**) `.gif` image to upload it on Facebook, Facebook tries to interpret it as a video:

[image: screen shot]

It cannot display thumbnail and when you click post, the posting will fail. Any text you have written will be discarded forever.

How to avoid this and upload GIF as any other photo?

Comment: Did you try changing the extension from `.gif` to `.png` or `.jpeg`?